# Correct permission for site, default and files folders?

Tags: users

I just need to know if these permission are corrects:

```
site --> 775
site/default -->775
site/default/files --> 775
site/default/setting.php --> 555
```

Comment: This question cannot be answered without knowing what the default user:group is on the files and what user and groups your webserver runs as. It should be closed as "unclear what you're asking". Alternatively as a duplicate of: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/373/what-are-the-recommended-directory-permissions

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually the permissions should be

```
sites -> 755
sites/default -> 755
sites/default/files -> 775
sites/default/settings.php -> 444
```

See the top 3 answers to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/373/what-are-the-recommended-directory-permissions) for some great details.

Comment: While upvoted and accepted, this is not a good answer. The question is incomplete and there is no way of knowing whether this answer is right for the OPs configuraton (or for anyone else).  Only thing good about it is the link.

Comment: Not to mention the directory is sites, not site. : D

Answer (score 5):

From [Drupal's official handbook](https://drupal.org/node/244924):

Copy this into a file and name it as "fix-permissions.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(id -u) != 0 ]; then
        printf "This script must be run as root.\n"
        exit 1
fi
drupal_path=${1%/}
drupal_user=${2}
httpd_group="${3:-www-data}"
# Help menu
print_help() {
cat <<-HELP
This script is used to fix permissions of a Drupal installation
you need to provide the following arguments:
1) Path to your Drupal installation.
2) Username of the user that you want to give files/directories ownership.
3) HTTPD group name (defaults to www-data for Apache).
Usage: (sudo) bash ${0##*/} --drupal_path=PATH --drupal_user=USER --httpd_group=GROUP
Example: (sudo) bash ${0##*/} --drupal_path=/usr/local/apache2/htdocs --drupal_user=john --httpd_group=www-data
HELP
exit 0
}
# Parse Command Line Arguments
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        case "$1" in
                --drupal_path=*)
drupal_path="${1#*=}"
;;
--drupal_user=*)
drupal_user="${1#*=}"
;;
--httpd_group=*)
httpd_group="${1#*=}"
;;
--help) print_help;;
*)
printf "Invalid argument, run --help for valid arguments.\n";
exit 1
esac
shift
done
if [ -z "${drupal_path}" ] || [ ! -d "${drupal_path}/sites" ] || [ ! -f "${drupal_path}/core/modules/system/system.module" ] && [ ! -f "${drupal_path}/modules/system/system.module" ]; then
printf "Please provide a valid Drupal path.\n"
print_help
exit 1
fi
if [ -z "${drupal_user}" ] || [ $(id -un ${drupal_user} 2> /dev/null) != "${drupal_user}" ]; then
printf "Please provide a valid user.\n"
print_help
exit 1
fi
cd $drupal_path
printf "Changing ownership of all contents of "${drupal_path}":\n user => "${drupal_user}" \t group => "${httpd_group}"\n"
chown -R ${drupal_user}:${httpd_group} .
printf "Changing permissions of all directories inside "${drupal_path}" to "rwxr-x---"...\n"
find . -type d -exec chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o= '{}' \;
printf "Changing permissions of all files inside "${drupal_path}" to "rw-r-----"...\n"
find . -type f -exec chmod u=rw,g=r,o= '{}' \;
printf "Changing permissions of "files" directories in "${drupal_path}/sites" to "rwxrwx---"...\n"
cd sites
find . -type d -name files -exec chmod ug=rwx,o= '{}' \;
printf "Changing permissions of all files inside all "files" directories in "${drupal_path}/sites" to "rw-rw----"...\n"
printf "Changing permissions of all directories inside all "files" directories in "${drupal_path}/sites" to "rwxrwx---"...\n"
for x in ./*/files; do
find ${x} -type d -exec chmod ug=rwx,o= '{}' \;
find ${x} -type f -exec chmod ug=rw,o= '{}' \;
done
echo "Done settings proper permissions on files and directories"
```

Now run this script as:
sudo bash fix-permissions.sh --drupal_path=your/drupal/path --drupal_user=your_user_name

Viola!  Your permissions are automatically fixed.

Comment: Make sure you read that whole post, and the comments.

Comment: And paste this file where? In what directory?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I decided to set permissions for my Drupal instance:

```
mkdir sites/default/files
chgrp -Rv apache sites/default/files
chmod 2775 sites/default/files
```

We do this by using 2775 in our chmod command. The 2 means that the group id will be preserved for any new files created in this directory. What that means is that apache will always be the group on any files, thereby ensuring that web server and the user will both always have write permissions to any new files that are placed in this directory. The first 7 means that the owner (example) can R (Read) W (Write) and X (Execute) any files in here. The second 7 means that group (www-data) can also R W and X any files in this directory. Finally, the 5 means that other users can R and X files, but not write.

Another point is to set correct permissions for your settings.php

```
chmod 444 sites/default/settings.php
```

Other permissions are to be default.

Complete Drupal Installation guide: http://itvictories.com/node/21

Answer (score 2):

Selected answer is not quite correct, especially when there are few unknowns there, however **Aleks** explained it quite extensively, and it's very similar approach that I take on Drupal sites.

Also, I thought I would share my script here as well, but as a Drupal Module, that I've created some time ago.
You can place it in `~/.drush` subdirectory and simply execute `drush file-permissions` while being in any working Drupal site subdirectory.

It bootstraps your Drupal site, checks for `file_private_path`, `file_public_path` and sets them to correct Apache user and group. Apache user / group is being determined automatically, so it's not relying on the user specifying them manually or having them hard-coded in a script file.

Module page: https://www.drupal.org/project/file_permissions

Comment: Would be great to port the module to Drupal 8

Comment: module doesn't change permission for tmp folder. Is that intentional?
In my configurtion tmp is set to site/default/tmp and no permission change is applied to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

As the other guys mentioned  the correct permission is

> All Drectories -> 755
> All files -> 755
> sites/default -> 755(this  override up rule this directory)
> sites/default/files -> 775 (this  override up rule for this directory and it's contents)
> sites/default/settings.php -> 444(this  override up rule for this file)

The appropriate commands to achieve mentioned Rules comes in the following,at the  root of your Drupal website

```
find . -type f | xargs chmod 644
find . -type d | xargs chmod 755
chmod 444 sites/default/settings.php
chmod 775 -R sites/default/files
```

to make it writeable by webserver you can use the following command

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t sites/default/files
```