# Where is tmp file directory?

Tags: files

Strangely I cannot find this directory anywhere inside sites or files. There is only one in /var would that be it? I need to edit the .htaccess as it states in my reports. Also what ownership and permissions should this display?

Ok I found it in directory above /var and deleted it then created it again and set it as 755 permissions with apache ownership and placed security script in .htaccess as given in reports link.

Update: the .htaccess in files and tmp folders to create more security shut me out! I had to remove them. OKAY finally worked this out and why looking for tmp folder in first place! A status report glitch error for files and tmp folder saying needed to add security .htaccess file is BOGUS! it is a bug of some sort in 7.24 for my system Centos linux so my removing them was exactly what I needed to do after adding erroneous security updates.

Comment: Did you check where is your tmp directory in  admin -> Configuration -> File System in your drupal system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your Drupal admin area at `/admin/config/media/file-system`

This will tell you where Drupal thinks it's `tmp` folder is currently set to.

Depending on your host provider you may or may not be able to write to that location.

The php-info report found on your Status Report page `admin/reports/status` can tell you where PHP's temp directory is defined to be on your system:

`upload_tmp_dir     no value`

Using htaccess, or `ini_set` in `settings.php` you can tweak where the upload temp directory is for your Drupal installation if need be.

Comment: I access via ssh and it is in cd /  the root of directory and now have changed to 777 permissions it is working again. my config is set to /tmp which also throws no errors

Comment: Your answer is informative for locating the folder- thanks. is 777 ok for permissions and chown apache:apache?

Comment: it would depend on your system. What it is your operating system? is it Fedora, Ubuntu, Centos? 777 is not a good number.

Comment: @CharlieBunt, you can but not need change it to 777, just change it to 755 work correctly .

Comment: There is not *one* configuration that is correct for shared hosting.  See the accepted answer this question to learn how to figure this out: [What are the most appropriate users and permission levels for Drupal sites on shared hosting?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52695/what-are-the-most-appropriate-users-and-permission-levels-for-drupal-sites-on-sh/53137#53137)