# What's the best files and directories permission for shared hosting

Tags: installation, security, files

i'm using a shared hosting for my Drupal Website and I'm having some security troubles especially with folders and files permissions.
So after some researches in the [official documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924) and some [group discussions](https://groups.drupal.org/node/12066) and even in [StackOverFlow answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52695/what-are-the-most-appropriate-users-and-permission-levels-for-drupal-sites-on-sh) , I made my configuration like this:

- Any Drupal php file: 444
- Drupal folders: 555
- SITES folder: 755
- SITES/DEFAULT folder: 505
- SITES/ALL folder: 705
- SITES/ALL files:604
- settings.php : 404
- SITES/DEFAULT/FILES folder: 775

Is there anything to correct or to adjsut for more security?

Comment: Don't overdo this. Just follow the official docs and you will be fine. Updates are much more important. What you do there with all these custom permissions can become difficult to maintain really fast.

Comment: I followed the documentation but it didnt work I met missing JS functionalities, upload files or even submitting nodes didnt work

Comment: A form not submitting probably wouldn’t be caused by file permissions, it sounds like you have different issues. Either way, the recommended directory permissions are what they are, all we could do is repeat the information from the other question here. Your current permissions aren’t similar to the recommended ones, so the first thing to do is fix those per the docs

Comment: @Clive but the form works fine again when i roll back the old permission