# What's the best file permission to drupal's files and directories?

Tags: security, files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the recommended directory permissions?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/373/what-are-the-recommended-directory-permissions)

I want to know what's the best file permission under a linux system to my drupal's files and directories including the files directory and the core either.
Thank you very much

Comment: There is also an answer here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52695/what-are-the-most-appropriate-users-and-permission-levels-for-drupal-sites-on-sh

Answer (score 2):

Drupal has already a well [documented page](http://drupal.org/node/244924) with all informations you are looking for.

Comment: The problem is that when i give the 644 permission to the "files" folder i don't see photos and media anymore

Comment: You don't have to give 644 for "files" folder, but "775", its needs read/write from owner and group and execute as it's folder.

Comment: But in the documentation they said that you don't have to give exeute permission to that folder

Comment: You don't have to give execution permission to Drupal files, but "files" folder should have it.