# Accidentally changed file permissions

Tags: files

In order to change a settings file, i accidentally replaced all files and folders permissions in folder "sites/default" to 777. Do i have to change all files and folders to 555?

Comment: Also http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/44072/10729 or http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/52695/10729

Comment: I would look at this documentation page for the proper file permissions for your entire Drupal site, there is even a script that you can install and run on your server if that sort of thing ever happens again. https://www.drupal.org/node/244924 and yes this may be a duplicate.