# Images problem after migration

Tags: media, migrations

I have a strange problem.
Today I moved a site from staging to production and the site work fine but I cannot se the images.

I can see in ftp the picture but drupal do not serve it in the page.
I already tryed to clear cache.

In the reports log I there is a lot of

```
Unable to generate the derived image located at public://styles/ensemble-small/public/anne ristorcelli s.png.
```

errors but I do not understand what I can do. 
The GD tookit works fine.. I checked it. 
I tryed to re-upload some images but do not work and I can't see they in the editing page too.

Can someone help me to solve this?

UPDATE: 
I tryed to delete the images generaten in the staging server to verify the correct working of the images modules. The images was ok.
So the problem is in server request?

If I try to see the image directly I have this error:

```
    Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, postmaster@ensemble05.it and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Comment: Do they come up and broken images, check if they have the correct permissions, and did you double check if you symlinked the folder, + check if your .htacesss

Comment: Check this one http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53537/unable-to-generate-the-derived-image?lq=1

Check if the image is in the folder, then check the permission of that specific image. did you do chmod -Rf 777 ?

Comment: The permission is 777 and I tryed to delete the GD generated images and refresh the page. The images was created as usual but when the browser ask drupal give me error 500 : The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. What I have to check in the .htaccess?

Comment: @Shyghar There should be errors in your web server log (Apache I'm guessing?) that correspond to the 500 responses. Are you able to check that log to find out what the underlying problem is?

Comment: Please edit your errors into your answer. As text. You don't expect people are willing to OCR your images to help you, do you? And it's 404 anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem going to sites/default/files/.htaccess file and commenting

```
# Options None
# Options +FollowSymLinks
```

After that I had some other broken images but there are some wrong address in the nodes  tags linked to
/subdirectory-of-staging-server/sites/default/files
instead
/sites/default/files

Thank you for all the comment who help me to debug the error ^^