# How do we configure SElinux to not break Drupal?

Tags: installation, files, database

I've installed Drupal on Red Hat 7 in Amazon Web Services, using a database on a separate RDS instance.

My original problem was that I couldn't make the Drupal installer recognize the /sites/default/ or /sites/default/files directories as writable, even after I confirmed they were writable by the ''apache'' user or temporarily set the permissions to writable by all. (This [year-old issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/90586/14252) may be similar.) When I filled in settings.php myself, then Drupal gave this connection error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'my-database-endpoint.rds.amazonaws.com' (13) in
>   lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /var/www/html/includes/lock.inc).

Disabling SElinux allows the installer to finish and allows Drupal to work. Re-enabling SElinux ('''setenforce 1''') stopped the installer; re-enabling SElinux after installation breaks Drupal, resulting in the same connection error given above. [Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/50280) mentions the problem, but doesn't give a specific solution for this case.

I figure many other people must have run into the same problem when installing Drupal.

Obviously I have to re-enable SElinux, so does anyone already know how to modify SElinux configurations to enable Drupal to work properly (and not degrade security)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are connecting to a remote host. You may need to allow httpd to make remote connections. Run these commands as root to set the SELinux variables.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

http://alexbilbie.com/2013/02/selinux-php-mysql/