# Use symlinks in the files directory

Tags: files

I use symlinks `sites/default/cdn` ( symlinks for /u01/cdn) instead of `sites/default/files/`. I've `chmod` two folders cdn is 777. But when I access the link `admin/config/media/file-system` and paste `sites/default/cdn` then displays following error; [image]

My permissions are:

[image]

Can you help me for my problem? please.
Thank you.

**Solution**

I have found problem. Only disable SELinux. use command: `setenforce 0` to disable SELinux.

Comment: The perms on the symlink don't matter, it's the perms on the target file/folder you need to change. Is /u01/cdn a physical folder or something special?

Comment: Thanks @Clive have helped support for me.
/u01 an ext disk(/dev/sda2 on /u01 type ext4 (rw)). and /u01/cdn is normal folder.
could you tell me how I can change perm to folder, please?use chmod?

Comment: And `sudo -u [web-server-user] touch /u01/cdn/test` works ok? No permission errors?

Comment: 'sudo -u apache' is not working. i Use 'sudo -v -u apache' and 'touch /u01/cdn/test' is successfully.

Comment: chown -R www-data.www-data /u01/cdn?

Comment: Yeah it's difficult to guess the exact command you need to run (it depends on how your server is set up). If you can get away with using pure POSIX perms then use the command @ar7max has suggested, replacing `www-data` with the username of your apache web server

Comment: `chown: invalid user: `www-data:www-data'`. I need create that user and group. Right?

Comment: You need to put there your apache user as Clive said above

Comment: I've added `chown -R apache:apache /u01/cdn` before but not success.
[link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/zjk7ilc6enl4ynv/8-21-2015%2017-59-43%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: @TrangLee I think you should give 755 to u01: `chmod 755 /u01` as currently this folder doesn't have write access.

Comment: Try this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/106809/50608 And I should ask you to put some more info next time, cuz, for example, we don't know on what OS your apahce works

Comment: @kenorb I have `chmod 755 /u01` and nothing changes. @ar7max I'm using CenOS 6.6, apache 2.2.15

Comment: @TrangLee Print again exactly your actual permissions: `ls -ld sites/default sites/default/files /u01 /u01/cdn` and re-edit your post with that info. Then double check [which user is used for your httpd server](http://serverfault.com/q/125865/130437).

Comment: @kenorb here is sceenshort http://imgur.com/MLVY5gq . and This problem occurs because I used ext disk, if I use another folder(ex: /var/www/cdn) then everything is normal. http://imgur.com/t0SnFvr

Comment: @TrangLee Check the perms of `sites/default/cdn` as well, as this is what you're trying to use, otherwise change the public path into `sites/default/files`.

Comment: Why sites/default/files owner is root?

Comment: `sites\default\files` is not problem, I want use `sites\default\cdn`.

Comment: Search a little and it seems no easy solution for your problem. As I understand its security issue

Comment: Thank you @ar7max and @ kenorb. I have found problem. That is SELinux. When I disable SELinux,  then The problem has been resolved. I am getting to know about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found problem. Only disable SELinux. Use command: `setenforce 0` to disable SELinux.