# Image style don't create thumb image and it get error "Division by zero"

Tags: media

My site is Drupal 7.36

Image style cann't create all images and it get 2 error messages

> Division by zero in theme_image_style_preview() (line 804 of /Users/snappy/Sites/betterpack/modules/image/image.admin.inc)
>
> array_intersect_key(): Argument #1 is not an array in theme_image_style_preview() (line 806 of /Users/snappy/Sites/betterpack/modules/image/image.admin.inc)

and I did:

> sudo chmod -R 777 sites/default/files/styles

It not work

Help me please.

Thank you everyone and sorry I write weak in English but I can read good English.

[image]
[image]

### ls command in sites/default/files/styles

> ls -l
>
> total 0
>
> drwxrwxrwx  3 _www  staff  102 Jun  7  2014 cover_article
>
> drwxrwxrwx  3 _www  staff  102 Mar 28 19:47 cover_product
>
> drwxrwxrwx  3 _www  staff  102 May  9  2014 large
>
> drwxrwxrwx  3 _www  staff  102 Jun  5  2014 medium
>
> drwxrwxrwx  3 _www  staff  102 Jun  6  2014 node_porduct
>
> drwxrwxrwx  3 _www  staff  102 Jun  6  2014 related_product
>
> drwxrwxrwx  3 _www  staff  102 Jun  7  2014 thumb_gallery_article
>
> drwxrwxrwx  3 _www  staff  102 May  9  2014 thumbnail

Comment: possible duplicate of [Division by zero in theme\_image\_style\_preview after moving to production server](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112839/division-by-zero-in-theme-image-style-preview-after-moving-to-production-server)

Comment: I had read that link and it don't has answer. 
Thanks @tunic

Comment: Can you post the ouput of ls -l sites/default/files/styles? If it's too long 10 or 20 lines are enought.

Comment: I posted output above

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your image toolkit is not working properly. On the status page (admin/reports/status) are there any errors, etc.?