# Access denied on image styles files on Drupal 7.34

Tags: 7, media

As you can see in the screenshot below, images that are processed through image styles aren't showing up and when trying to display them through their urls, we get a 403 access denied.

It's a fresh drupal install on a Debian 7 with no additional modules

Any ideas are welcome to overcome this problem

Thanks

[image]

Comment: check your files folder permissions and owners...

Comment: I checked. Permissions are messed up. When i install drupal locally (os X) it works fine but on debian, drupal creates folders with incorrect permissions. I'm thinking it has to do with the way htaccess interacts with the environment but have no idea how to fix it.I tried editing root and sites/default/files .htaccess files but it didn't help. Here are the permissions of the files directory (and its subdirectories : files drwxrwxr-x, files/field drwx------, files/styles drwxrwxr-x, ../styles/large drwx------, ..large/public drwx------, field drwx------, image drwxrwxr-x, image.jpg -rw-rw-r--

Comment: It's not caused by htaccess, it's caused by how apache and php are invoked as processes. The typical setup nowadays would be to create a new user, assign that to the www group, give it limited permissions (no shell etc) and then run php via fcgi using vanilla ini. The user & config gets sandboxed, and files in the web root inherit its permissions, making things safer. The problem is that if you're managing files as a different user (FTP / ssh / VCS) the file owner and the webroot owner / process owner get mixed up, resulting in conflicting permissions.

Answer (score 2):

It's common to have incorrect permissions on that folder. You'll need to fix the permissions for `/site/default/files` directory. For a complete answer, see [the recommended directory permissions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/373/) or just run the following from the website root (per [@David](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/7153/david-thomas)'s comment below).

```
find sites/default/files -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
find sites/default/files -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
chown -R www-data:www-data sites/default/files
```

For additional issues, check Status Reports on `yourWebsiteName.com/admin/reports/status`.

## Update:

I think I found the issue.

There was a [similar question asked on Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/2379397).

It seems that the issue is that certain hosts, such as BlueHost, HostMonster and Virtualmin forbid `+FollowSymLinks`. You will need to change `+FollowSymLinks` into `+SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` in your `.htaccess` file. See an entire [discussion on Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/1269780).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was just that sites/default/files had the rights set as 544 but needed to be 744. 
I am not sure why the prohibition of write results in the unability to read. So as this is a bit unintuitive I thought it might be useful for anybody with the same problem.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Terminal by pressing Ctrl+T
Type : 
`cd /var/www/drupal` ( assuming it to be the drupal root for your site )

sudo chmod 777 -R sites/default/files

Now clear cache and try to update the previously created image style

Comment: You are assuming they are on Ubuntu (as I believe you are) which is not always the case. Also using is not only a bad advice but at many cases wouldn't even work.

Comment: indeed. @timofey is the correct answer