# Configuring a public file directory & sub-directories

Tags: files

I'm doing some configuration updates to my site and I had a question regarding the permission configurations. I've setup a directory on the base level of site titled "publicuploads" which I've added into the "Public file system path" as "publicuploads".

It's permissions are currently set to 755.

After looking around my site's directory though, I am noticing though that the files and sub-directories inside of that directory are varying between 755, 775, and 644.

**My question:** What are the appropriate permissions be for this public directory?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the recommended directory permissions?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/373/what-are-the-recommended-directory-permissions)

Comment: @ShawnConn: I believe they are relating, however, the link that they reference in the answer: https://www.drupal.org/node/244924 does not provide me with clear answers. Would you be able to explain this more clearly in the method I've referenced above? (Using numeric rather than rwx).