# File Transfer failed, reason: Cannot create directory /var/www/html/modules

Tags: 8, installation

I have installed Drupal 8 on EC2. I am trying to install a module (`simple_sitemap-8.x-2.5.tar.gz`).

When I use the interface, I get a failed transfer message:

[image]

I have `chmod a+x` the directory (which already exists), but to no avail.

How should I solve this one? Is there a workaround to install modules without FTP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the recommended directory permissions?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/373/what-are-the-recommended-directory-permissions)

Answer (score 5):

The `chmod a+x` isn't enough, the directory should have write permission for HTTP server user, so try:

```
chmod 755 /var/www/html
```

<sup>Prefix with `sudo` if it's necessary.</sup>

or if you've already some files in it, try:

```
chmod -R u+rwX,go+rX,go-w /var/www/html
```

and if you're using Apache, you should change the ownership by:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

If `www-data` is not correct, you can find the Apache user by the following command:

```
ps axho user,comm|grep -E "httpd|apache"|uniq|grep -v "root"|awk 'END {if ($1) print $1}
```

Comment: As an alternative, you can use `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` to find the Apache user name.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming you're using Ubuntu as your EC2 OS:**

If you were to use FTP, right now it would work, while browser install method doesn't. To allow browser method to work:

```
cd /var/www/html

sudo chown www-data -R modules
```

Note that the browser method works now, but FTP won't work. In the future, if you decide to use FTP, you will need to switch it back to ubuntu as the folder owner:

```
cd /var/www/html

sudo chown ubuntu -R modules
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this may sound silly but I've had the same issue and all I had to do was unblock the port 21/22 on my EC2's Security Group. Thought maybe as simple as that -- I had been stuck for over an hour on permissions.