# video embed field module folder path

Tags: 7, views

I have placed the video embed field module in the location sites/all/modules/contrib/video embed field. Now I have problem with generating youtube thumbnail.Is that path I uploadwed the module is correct or need to change the module to some where

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you've uploaded the module to the correct location (otherwise you wouldn't have been able to install it).

Failure to generate thumbnails could theoretically be caused by a number of different configuration problems, but the most common would probably be either:

- incorrect permissions on sites/default/files (or a subfolder)
- something blocking the outgoing request to download the thumbnail from YouTube's servers.

Check your server logs and Drupal's watchdog for errors, if there are none you'll probably need to step through the code to find out exactly where and why it's failing.

Comment: how to set permission to the folder

Comment: Depends on what you need. Use https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/373/what-are-the-recommended-directory-permissions as a guide, but unless you're sure you know what you're doing get a sysadmin to help you