# How to set up permissions for the private files directory?

Tags: 8, security, files

I'm trying to set up the private files directory and I'm getting the following error.

> The backup file could not be saved to 'private://backup_migrate/'
>   because the directory could not be created or cannot be written to.
>   Please make sure your private files directory is writable by the web
>   server.

Could someone help correct my misstep? I've scoured scads of pages of documentation, and oddly I don't seem to be able to find a reliable path to a solution. Lots of conflicting info and lots of missing details.

Here's my setup:

1. [bitnami drupal image](https://bitnami.com/stack/drupal) (centos)
2. path to Drupal /root/apps/drupal/htdocs
3. I've connected as root via ssh

Here are the exact steps I've followed, and which best reflect my understanding so far of what I should do:

1. `# cd /root/apps/drupal/` to go to directory that contains the web root directory
2. `# mkdir private-files`
3. `# drush dl file_permissions --destination=~/.drush` to download the contributed [file_permissions utility](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_permissions), which says it handles all necessary permissions changes
4. `# nano sites/default/settings.php` to tell Drupal where to find the directory, set `$settings['file_private_path'] = '/root/apps/drupal/private-files';`
5. `# drush cr` to clear Drupal and Drush caches
6. `# drush fp` to run the file_permissions utility; it responds:

   > Your httpd user: daemon                                      [status]
   >   Your httpd group: daemon                                     [status]
   >   You will be prompted for admin password to be able to change [warning]
   >   permissions with `sudo` command.
   >   Security warning: Couldn't write .htaccess file. Please create a     [error]
   >   .htaccess file inyour private:// directory which contains the
   >   following lines: <pre><code># Deny all requests from Apache 2.4+.
   >   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
   >   Require all denied
   >   </IfModule>
   >
   > # Deny all requests from Apache 2.0-2.2.
   >   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   >   Deny from all
   >   </IfModule>
   >   # Turn off all options we don't need.
   >   Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews
   >
   > # Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
   >   SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
   >   <Files*>
   >   # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
   >   SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
   >   </Files>
   >   # If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
   >   <IfModule mod_php5.c>
   >     php_flag engine off
   >   </IfModule></code></pre>
7. `# drush cr` to clear Drupal and Drush caches
8. `# ls -al` to see permissions; it shows:

   > total 8628
   >   drwxr-xr-x  7 root   root       134 Jul 23 12:04 .
   >   drwxr-xr-x  5 root   root        53 Jun  7 13:52 ..
   >   lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root        14 Jun  7 13:55 .bitnamimeta -> ../../var/meta
   >   -r-xr--r--  1 root   root   8826689 Jun  7 13:31 bnconfig
   >   drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root       146 Jun  7 13:51 conf
   >   drwxr-xr-x 12 root   root      4096 Jun  7 13:51 drush
   >   drwxr-x---  9 root   daemon    4096 Jul 18 13:46 htdocs
   >   drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root        25 Jun  7 13:51 licenses
   >   drwxrwsr-x  2 daemon daemon      23 Jul 23 13:45 private-files
   >   lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root        33 Jun  7 13:54 updateip -> /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/bnconfig
9. `# ls -al private-files/` to see permissions; it shows:

   > total 4
   >   drwxrwsr-x 2 daemon daemon  23 Jul 23 13:45 .
   >   drwxr-xr-x 7 root   root   134 Jul 23 12:04 ..
   >   -rw-r--r-- 1 root   daemon 687 Jul 23 13:47 .htaccess

Needless to say, pretty frustrating since I've spent at least 4 hrs on what I imagine must be simple for someone already familiar with all the components.

Since I am new to servers as well as to Drupal, please break out actual steps vs merely invoking (vague-to-me) concepts such as 'change user group' or the like.

Comment: Are you running drush as root? That's not going to help because any files created by drush will not be writable by the webserver. Better to run it as the daemon user to reduce the chance of file ownership issues.

Comment: Thanks - I've come across instructions on acting as a different user. Will do that and follow the same steps above. I'm assuming no one actually sees issues with those steps other than doing things as root user? (btw, I've been following bitnami instructions, which don't mention the need to act as a different user....).

Comment: As the original poster of this question, I want to be sure to understand the considerations of setting up private files no matter the platform. For those editing my question to make it more specific to bitnami: please avoid doing so lightly. I don't believe Bitnami has some unique secret in this regard. Please address that uniqueness if in fact it's the case.

Comment: Sorry but that would be much too broad for a single question in this format. There are many different environments with many different considerations, too many to cover in a couple of paragraphs. File permissions are file permissions at the end of the day - Drupal just needs to be able to write to two folders (public and private), and read from the rest of the docroot. How you get that to happen across multiple platforms isn't something that Drupal is concerned with, it only cares about the _result_, and nothing in and of Drupal itself will teach you *nix file permissions

Comment: @clive - a polite request, since I'm attempting to learn - please note the above request and revert my question to my own title of a moment ago unless you are able to describe why this issue is specific to the Bitnami platform. Is there reason to believe that bitnami needs special permissions, ownership, locations or other consideration? Alternatively, please feel free to point me to an existing answer that actually covers all the details. I've not found one.

Comment: To put it succinctly: this is a file permission problem, not unique to Drupal, and we wouldn't teach you what you want us to teach you here (how to manage generic file permissions on any platform). It's been made specific to your current environment, in an attempt to avoid it being closed as "too broad" or otherwise off topic, because the knowledge you need is not unique to Drupal, but there\s an outside chance that there might be something unique to Bitnami that can be identified and addressed to help you and future users of the same platform

Comment: I will respectfully disagree, knowing you have a lot of experience on Stack Exchange. Please reconsider your stance. I'm unable to find a detailed explanation of Drupal's full requirements for private files, or a trouble-shooting guide. A good answer here will be a service to the community.

Comment: Drupal's full file permission requirements are very well documented: https://www.drupal.org/node/244924. The problem you're experiencing is not knowing how to set up your operating system/environment to fulfil those requirements. Drupal also requires MySQL and PHP, a web server, etc, but a question on how to install those wouldn't be on topic here either. I do understand it's something people do need to cover, that's why we deliberately let this question through the cracks: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/373/what-are-the-recommended-directory-permissions. That's never going to be..

Comment: ...a full tutorial, though, you need to extract the information from there, combine it with knowledge of how to administer the server, and come up with a solution that matches your exact needs

Comment: Again with respect, Clive (and I know it's hard to convey in text, but sincerely!) - that page does not document requirements of private files. Please have another look (you can use your browser keyword find function with 'private') and reconsider. If someone is able to improve that page, I'd be a huge fan!

Comment: You're right, it doesn't, my bad. But that doesn't change the fact that what you need to know _isn't about Drupal_. You already know all the Drupal parts of this, which are basically 1. that the folder needs to be read/writeable by the user that executes the PHP part of the website, and 2. you need to set the path to it under Admin -> Config -> Media. There's nothing else to know from the Drupal perspective, everything else is about how to set up appropriate users/permissions to allow PHP to write to the folder

Comment: Thanks for the additional details, Clive. Unfortunately it does not seem that the 2 items you list in fact cover the requirements. There must still be something missing, as user, permissions and path all appear to be correct according to documentation, yet the error message persists. The strength of Stack Exchange is that a community can pool their knowledge; my request continues to be that the question continue to specify a need for details, and that the bitnami platform be an aside vs a primary point.

Comment: Ok I give :) I've edited into the more generic version - like I said before, I can't promise that's not going to make it attract "too broad" close votes (if I wasn't a mod and didn't have a binding vote I'd be voting it as such if I'm honest). Good luck getting it sorted anyway

Comment: Thanks Clive - I appreciate your efforts, and those of other long-time users, in keeping quality here high. There do seem to be unknown/unstated specifics regarding the private-files directory, and as you acknowledge, some holes in official documentation. I plan to help edit the Drupal docs page once I have a bit more clarity (ideally with similar help in making sure my edits are accurate and useful).

Answer (score 3):

Your Drupal folder is owned by `daemon:daemon` and your private files directory is owned by `root:root`.

Fix it by making your private files directory at least owned by the same group:

`$ chown -R daemon:daemon /root/apps/drupal/private-files`

---

Sorry, I reread your `ls -la` output again, this time on a bigger screen, and it seems to be the other way around. Your
private files folder is already owned by `daemon:daemon` where in this setup it should be `root:root` instead:

`$ chown -R root:root /root/apps/drupal/private-files`

---

After reading through this thread from 2013 https://community.bitnami.com/t/how-in-bitnami-cloud-drupal-set-up-a-secure-private-file-system-path-folder/9652 it seems your files and folders ownership got messed. Seems that all your Drupal including private files should indeed recursively be owned by `daemon:daemon`. Generally, logging in as `root` should be avoided.

Comment: I have recursively set owner and group to daemon:daemon using $ chown -R daemon:daemon /root/apps/drupal/ --unfortunately the issue persists (I've confirmed all Drupal files/directories have that ownership and cleared caches several times with $ drush cr). I'm editing my original question to include this info.

Comment: Hi Clive - I notice you rolled back my edits, and I understand your doubts about this question broadly. Seems useful to me to include the changes mentioned here as an update to my question. Would doing so still be in keeping with the guidelines of the community?

Comment: @OwnSourcingstudent – I'm considering it, or to update the docs on drupal.org. But I guess I won't have the time until later this day or tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I would not create the folder as root, let the site create its own folder. Just set the path in your settings.php and then go to 'File system' in the Drupal site (configuration). You can see your path reflected here. Then just save the form and Drupal will create the folders with right permissions.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried first. It reflects the correct path in the file system ("Private file system path /root/apps/drupal/private-files") but I still get the error.

Comment: How should that ever work when your private files path exists outside Drupal's web root in a directory where Drupal has no write permission for?

Comment: @leymannx it does work, you can fill in ../private and have Drupal create a folder on it's own, even if it's outside of the webroot.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks like this:

```
Your httpd user: daemon [status]
Your httpd group: daemon [status]

# ls -al /root/apps/drupal/private-files
total 4
drwxrwsr-x 2 daemon daemon 23 Jul 23 13:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 134 Jul 23 12:04 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root daemon 687 Jul 23 13:47 .htaccess
```

On a *vanilla* *nix system, that is *all* it takes to give `daemon` full access to the `private-files` directory.  I.e. when the Drupal **Backup and Migrate** tries to create `'private://backup_migrate/` it *should* be allowed to to so.  As indicated by the error message you've posted, it is *not*.

Finding: You're *not* running a vanilla *nix system.
So what can be wrong?

There is no way of knowing without knowing a lot more about your server configuration, but given that you're running *CentOS*, I suspect that you're having an issue with something known as "[*SELinux*](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux)". Btw. *SELinux* is great!  But it imposes an extra layer of security that sometimes comes as an surprise to the uninitiated.

Basically, if *SELinux* is in use, to fix permissions – in addition to the mod-bits – you *also* you need to make sure that the *security* policy for your `private-files` directory allows `daemon` to create subdirectories there.

First navigate to the the Drupal configuration directory (`sites/default`) and inspect the security context label for the public file upload directory:

```
$ ls -Z .
drwxrwxr x. daemon daemon unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 files
```

The label here is `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`.

Then make sure that `private-files`is tagged with the *same* label. Navigate to `/root/apps/drupal` and a give command similar to this (use the label used on *your* configuration):

```
$ sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t private-files
```

(Source: http://heim.ifi.uio.no/gisle/staging2/drupalprimer/drupal/cf_files.html#f_selinux)

Comment: Thanks for this detail, @free-radical. Great explanation, and strikes me as a likely explanation, but `# sestatus` returns `SELinux status: disabled`. I'd guess it's consequently no surprise that `# ls -Z sites/default/` returns a question mark for the security context label for the public file upload dir: `drwxrwsr-x daemon daemon ? files`. Interested whether there's another buried detail that similarly bears checking.

Comment: I agree: SELinux is disabled.  That rules out SELinux as the culprit. Unfortunately, I cannot think of any *other* things that may cause this.  Things to try: 1) Contact bitnami support and user forums; 2) Go over your configuration again, look for spelling errors and other trivial mistakes; 3) ditch your vhost - start from scratch. Going over your description agian, I see nothing wrong in the way you've tried to set this up.