# Not able to access uploaded images in AWS

Tags: files

1. When we upload an image using the URL 'https://website.com/file/add' , the image is **getting uploaded**. While uploading, we have chosen the destination as ' Public local files served by the webserver' and the media folder as 'Media Root'.
2. But when we hover over the uploaded image inside https://website.com/admin/content/file, its showing "**The file doesn't exist**".
3. And when we try to access the uploaded image, then **either** of the following messages would show up:-

   1. **Warning: filesize(): stat failed for public://download (2).jpg in file_save()(line 614 of /var/www/html/website/includes/file.inc)**.
   2. **Page not Found Error - The requested The requested URL "/sites/default/files/image.jpg" was not found on this server**.

My website is working under Drupal 7(7.63) and hosted in AWS. There are 2 servers under a load balancer. PHP:- Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17. The public directory mentioned in the file system is 'sites/default/files' and it has given 777 permission.

Could anyone please guide me on how to solve this issue? Is this issue related to server-specific configurations?

Thanks

Comment: `My website is working under Drupal 7(7.63)` There was a security update in 7.65. You should update to the latest, as of this writing, [7.66](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases?api_version%5B%5D=103)

Answer (score 0):

> ## Configuration examples
>
> For example, on many systems the Apache process runs as a user called
>   "www-data" that is in a group called "www-data". This user should be
>   able to read all of the files in your Drupal directory either by group
>   permissions or by "other" permissions. It should not have write
>   permissions to the code in your Drupal directory. If you use features
>   of Drupal which require the "files" directory, then give the www-data
>   user the permission to write files only in that directory.
>
> The following is an example file listing of a safe configuration
>   showing two files in a site where uploaded files are stored in the
>   "files" directory. In order to see the file permissions set for your
>   setup, go to the command line and type: `ls -al`.
>
> ```
> drwxrwx---  7 www-data    greg-group  4096 2008-01-18 11:02 files/
> drwxr-x--- 32 greg-user   www-data    4096 2008-01-18 11:48 modules/
> -rw-r-----  1 greg-user   www-data     873 2007-11-13 15:35 index.php
> ```
>
> <sub>source: [Securing file permissions and
>   ownership](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924)</sub>

Your issue is that the /files folder has the wrong owner. (The 1st one is the owner, the 2nd is the group).

In SSH command line, you need to do:

```
cd /var/www/html/website/sites/default
```

For checking purposes do

```
ls -al
```

You will see that your files folder has the wrong owner. (The 1st one is the owner, the 2nd is the group).

To fix it, now do:

```
sudo chown www-data:<the-group-name> -R files
```

**Note:** Replace `<the-group-name>` with your actual group name, without the `<>` part. I'm just indicating it's a place holder.

> **DO NOT DO:**
>
> ```
> NOTE: THIS IS AN INSECURE CONFIGURATION
> drwxrwx---  7 www-data  www-data  4096 2008-01-18 11:02 files/
> drwxrwx--- 32 greg-user www-data  4096 2008-05-16 11:48 modules/
> -rw-rw-rw-  1 www-data  www-data   873 2007-11-13 15:35 index.php
> ```
>
> <sub>source: [Securing file permissions and
>   ownership](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924)</sub>

Related:

- [What are the recommended directory permissions?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/16994/27710)

Comment: Thank you No Sssweat for providing me with the solution in detail. Currently the owner:group is www-data:www-data for '/files' folder. Could you please help me on how to get the real group name of the owner 'www-data'?

Comment: `www-data` user's group name is `www-data`. What you want is to use the group name of your commanline user. If you're on ubuntu use ubuntu. If it's root use root. If you type the command `groups` that will list you all the groups.

Comment: Basically use the usernane you used to login to SSH, as tipically their group name is the same name. So `www-data:<ssh-user-group>`

Comment: ok I have tried changing the group of www-data for 'files' folder. But still the issue persists. What shall be the solution now? Is the issue related to :- 1.Missing of  policy to the user/group you are using under "Identity & Access Management."
2. Missing of certificate.
3. .htaccess  problems: Options +FollowSymLinks present in the current htaccess.